# Spring Cloud Gateway cache

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am testing Spring Cloud Gateway 2.0.0 M9. Is possible to cache a response in Spring Cloud Gateway API? The idea is to cache and URL with some parameters in the same way than a proxy cache. Maybe through a filter or predicate?

I know is possible to make a circuit break with Hystrix so it would be something similar.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WorkflowGatewayApiApplication {

@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("path_route", r -> r.predicate(conf -> <IF_CACHE_RETURN_CACHE?>)
               .path("/testapps")       
               .uri("http://httpbin.org/"))
            .build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WorkflowGatewayApiApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: There is a hystrix filter already, but caching is not enabled. Writing a cache filter doesn't seem like a difficult thing to do, but there is no support at this time.

Comment: You are probably talking about caching a response with Reactor.
There are two ways:
CacheMono (https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheMono.html) or using Mono.cache(Duration ttl) https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/current/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.htm